# matplotlib get histogram values pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Pandas has a built in implementation of matplotlib's histogram method for use with dataframes. I want to be able to get the values of each bin. I am able to do this by converting my dataframe column into a list with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100))
df.columns = ['mydata']

myarray = df.mydata[(df.mydata > 0)].tolist()  # This is a list
weights = np.ones_like(myarray)/len(myarray)
hist = plt.hist(myarray, bins=10, weights=weights)
plt.show()

counts, bins, bars = hist
print counts
```

But when I do this with pandas' implementation of hist, as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100))
df.columns = ['mydata']

myarray = df.mydata[(df.mydata > 0)]  # This is a pandas Series
weights = np.ones_like(myarray)/len(myarray)
hist = myarray.hist(bins=10, weights=weights)
plt.show()

counts, bins, bars = hist
print counts
```

I get this:

```
TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not iterable
```

Does anyone know a way to get the histogram values off a histogram generated by pandas' hist method? Thanks!

Comment: The `pandas` implementation of `hist` does not return the counts, bins and patches that you get from `matplotlib`'s version. Instead, it returns the `Axes` that it plotted the histogram on. If you check the duplicate I linked above, I show a way you can back out the `counts` and `bins` from the `patches` associated with the `Axes` returned by `pandas`; but its probably easier to just use `plt.hist`.

Comment: Good find tom. Thank you!